# Emails sent through my email address are received to client's spam folder

Tags: email, spam-prevention, email-spam

I am sending emails through my domain and it receives to spam folder of clients. Even I heard that email sent to gmail account are also received to spam folder.

I check with my hosting provider for all necessary configuration related to email sending are configured correctly. I am using dedicated IP, separate cpanel account,  PTR and DMARC are set properly and enabled valid DKIM and SPF records for my domain.

I also tested the spaminess of the domain using a third-party online tool and the results were 10/10 which means they are fully authenticated.

Another thing I double check the content of the messages with spam tables. The content of the email should not look like SPAM.

Please help me with this issue.

Best regards,
Vijay

Comment: If you are able to look at the headers on the email that was received and placed in the spam folder, it might reveal the reason.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... Where I can check the reason?